# Vue.js $emit + v-for, как получить данные о текущем элементе в списке при пользовательском событии с дочернего компонента?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

есть родительский компонент в через v-for перебираются дочерние компоненты, при событии в дочерном компоненте хочется передать какие-то данные из дочернего, а так же узнать в родительском в каком из детей произошло событие и взять данные сопутсвующие этому дочернему компоненту

Например из примера ниже:
сейчас при клике на child // -> some-value
а хочется // -> some-value и p.name

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<span @click="click" class="child">child</span>',
  data: function () {
    return {}
  },
  methods: {
    click: function () {
     this.$emit('customevent', 'some-value')
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    ps: [
     {'name': 'p1'},
     {'name': 'p2'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    customChildEvent: function (value) {
      console.log(value)
      // выведет some-value
      // хочется чтобы сюда попало значение из нажатого "p"
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.child {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer
}
.child:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <div v-for="p in ps">
    <p>
      {{p.name}} +
      <child @customevent="customChildEvent"></child>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Родитель не получает потомков, как и потомок родителя; это часть философии `Vue.js` ради модульности.
Если идентификация всё же необходима (повод пересмотреть связность) - можно передать имя потомку и нужно чтобы он его возвращал:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ["name"],
  template: '<span @click="click" class="child">child</span>',
  data: function () {
    return {}
  },
  methods: {
    click: function () {
        // this.name - переданное родителем свойство
     this.$emit('customevent', 'some-value', this.name)
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    ps: [
     {'name': 'p1'},
     {'name': 'p2'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    customChildEvent: function (value, name) {
      console.log(value, name); // eg, "some-value", "p1"
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.child {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer
}
.child:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <div v-for="p in ps">
    <p>
      {{p.name}} +
      <child @customevent="customChildEvent" :name="p.name"></child>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: повод пересмотреть связность - Vuex?

Comment: @ЖалгасАжибаев, как вариант.

Answer (score 1):

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<span @click="click" class="child">child</span>',
  data: function () {
    return {}
  },
  methods: {
    click: function () {
     this.$emit('customevent', 'some-value')
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    ps: [
     {'name': 'p1'},
     {'name': 'p2'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    customChildEvent: function (data) {
      console.log('name', data.name)
      console.log('value', data.value)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.child {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer
}
.child:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example">
  <div v-for="p in ps">
    <p>
      {{p.name}} +
      <child @customevent="customChildEvent({name: p.name, value: $event})"></child>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Other, как вам такой вариант, здесь можно не передавать имя потомку, а главное РАБОТАЕТ! ))))